# Highcharts Stock Chart - Custom X axis date times format

Tags: highcharts, formatter, x-axis

I'm wondering if it's possible to define a custom ordering or format for the xAxis in stock highcharts. My dataset has a date time which would be used for the xAxis however my client has specified that it should show in the middle T-0 on the xAxis. Rest of them from the left side should be like -3m -2m -1m and from the right side +1m +2m +3m(In case of year timeframe).

Example for  1 year timeframe

[image: 1]

I have tried using formatter function on  xAxis labels. However I can not figure out how to get the middle tick first and then start chaging labels to the left and to the right from that middle position tick.

Answer (score 0):

If the formatting, amount and interval of the labels is static, you can use variables from outside of the chart.

For example:

```
const labels = [];
let labelIndex = 0;

for (let i = -6; i < 7; i++) {
  labels.push(i);
}

Highcharts.stockChart('container', {
  xAxis: {
    ...,
    labels: {
      formatter: function() {
        labelIndex++;
        if (this.isFirst) {
          labelIndex = 0;
        }
        const label = labels[labelIndex];

        if (label < 0) {
          return label + 'm';
        } else if (label === 0) {
          return 'T-' + label;
        }

        return '+' + label + 'm';
      }
    }
  },
  ...
});
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/L7uy29kw/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/xAxis